# Yahoo email compose link not working - compose.mail.yahoo.com

Tags: email, yahoo, email-client, webmail

We are trying to open Yahoo Compose Email programmatically via JavaScript.
It was working fine till now but suddenly it stopped working.

The Yahoo Compose Box opens but with empty fields, it does not populate any information like "subject" and "body".

Example- 
http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?Subject=TestSubject&Body=TestBody&To=test@yahoo.com

It will redirect to Yahoo neo launcher with blank compose window
https://us-mg6.mail.yahoo.com/neo/launch?action=compose&.rand=813078417

Comment: The query string params are not being pass to the neo launcher url in the redirect. And manually adding the params doesn't work either. Yahoo need to address this on their end.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Yes, we are also waiting for Yahoo to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Came across this and found the answer.

`http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=TO&subject=SUBJECTMap&body=BODY`

Of course change TO, SUBJECT, and BODY

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem discovered that I could append the url params to the new launcher url and remove the .rand param and it would work.

Like this

https://us-mg6.mail.yahoo.com/neo/launch?action=compose&Subject=TestSubject&Body=TestBody&To=test@yahoo.com

Comment: This will not work because the URL is hard-coded in your case which is pointing to  https://us-mg6 server